# How can I stop an application from updating itself?

Tags: applications

*Not to be confused with applications auto updates.*

I have this application as an APK file, once I install the application and choose open it starts working perfectly yet it starts downloading a newest version of itself which **I dont want to** for a certain reason.

[image]

The application is a full screen IPTV application. It runs on an Android box. It can be rooted as it's version 4.2.2. The application has no menus or option, it's not available on the store nor it has a specific name.

Disabling the "Uknown Sources" is not a good solution as I would have the "install blocked" message popping up every two minutes or less since the application does NOT give up on trying to update itself.

[image]

[image]

Obviously disabling the Internet access is not a solution.

Is there any solution that does not require modifying the APK file itself? I know nothing about Java development and it is impossible for me to modify the source code unless it can be modified to achieve my goal using a for-dummies software like [APK Editor](http://www.revdl.com/apk-editor-pro-android.html/)

Comment: Turn off ye interwebs, then open the app and see if auto-updates can be turned off.

Comment: @DanBrown would you care to explain a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: Turn off WiFi and mobile data (or just enable airplane mode.) Then open the app. find the apps settings menu (wherever that is) and look for an option along the lines of 'Automatic updates'

Comment: @DanBrown thanks for your suggestion but I believe you have not read my question carefully

Comment: I have - What app is it? (so i can have a look around)

Comment: @DanBrown it's not available in the store

Comment: @Ulkoma, the Dan Brown suggestion seems legit to me. Doesn't the app have a settings menu? Try find something about update

Comment: @Ulkoma I can look online. **what app is it?**

Comment: @esQmo I should mentioned in the question that the app have no menu at all, it's poorly developed for sure otherwise it wouldn't try to update itself in this crazy way

Comment: @Ulkoma, I would like to point out that sometimes these "updates" that we don't like as users are necessary for the app to continue contacting the necessary server database and back-end stuff. Also, DanBrown is suggesting that you try isolating the app from the source of its update by turning off your internet/WiFi/Cellular connections. During this time, see if there are options WITHIN THE APP (not within the app store) to disable auto-updates.

Comment: Just so you know, you can even disable the Install Blocked dialogs. See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/132951/96277

Comment: @Firelord I'll check that later on, this might solve my problem, if it's the case then I'll ask you to put it as answer so I can grant you the bounty

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an app such as [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) which has live capture capabilities to find the IP of the update server your app is accessing.

You can then add an entry to iptables to drop the connections to that IP.

For the changes to persist across reboots you'd need a kernel with init support. So you'd have to check that out as well and instal custom one if needed.

PS: I want to make clear that I have no real experience with actually trying any of it and that my answer is just put together from answers I found on other questions on Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. In particular, [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98374/196482) and [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/85643/196482).

Comment: Killing the connection stops the main function of the app, it's a live TV app

Comment: you'd need root for that

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 methods which I suggest you try out:

1. Change time and date settings either ahead or behind and see if that could trick the application into not updating itself. Some apps can be auto updating depending on time and date.
2. Go to phone settings, and open Data usage. Check if the controversial app is listed there. If it's listed then click on menu and Restrict background data.

Now that you have done any of the methods above open the app and try to check its settings to see if has an option to prevent auto updating.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1**

You can disable auto-updates for every application that is installed on the device you're using via the Play Store. Visit the app's store page and at the top there is a 3 dot button that says Auto-Update. This feature is enabled by default and you can disable for each individual app.

But unfortunately, you can't edit or modify the APK itself using a APK editor program because auto-update is made by the device itself.

**METHOD 2**

In the Play Store, touch the menu button in the upper-left corner of the screen.

[image]

Touch “Settings” on the menu.

[image]

The “Auto-update apps” option is in the “General” section of the “Settings” screen. If it says “Auto-update apps at any time. Data charges may apply,” then your apps will be automatically updated. To turn this option off, touch “Auto-update apps.”
]

On the “Auto-update apps” dialog box, touch “Do not auto-update apps.”

The dialog box closes and the “Auto-update apps” option is updated with the “Do not auto-update apps” setting. Touch the Play Store icon in the upper-left corner of the screen to go back to the main Play Store screen. You can also touch the Back button on your device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The app has not been installed via Play Store, also I have mentioned that it's not auto update, the app is designed to request a newer copy of itself

Comment: @Ulkoma So, you cannot do anything about it. Because it's integrated inside the app. You can't also edit the APK as I've mentioned. But you can try to edit. I don't have much experience about editing APK's but you can only try. And a question, is this app has a bigger size that you don't want it to update itself?

Comment: never say never, maybe someone will come up with a way to disable the system notifications or a firewall to block the download. No idea about the size

Comment: @Ulkoma maybe... :D

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on your Android version. If you carrying least lollipop, you will get an option in setting. Or you can simply visit to play store by searching your app. There just disable the auto update option.

Comment: The app is not in the store and it has no options, it simply requests a new version of itself and invokes the installer, any idea how to defeat that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this App [Mobiwol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall&hl=en)
Which,

- can make enable/disable each/all app to connect/disconnect the Mobile data/Wi-fi/both.
- Block background app activity

> To do this, just Slide the firewall to enable

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: Mobiwol App Connectivity Permission]

> The Blue highlighted one in Fig. 2 shows the App is allowed to connect.

**Note: No root is required & works from version 4.0**